# How to add value in a $.ajax url in CakePHP 2

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Im trying to use ajax to sent request. I have CartsController and a method add. Please help!

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link('Add', array('controller'=>'carts', 
'action'=>'add', 'product_id'=>$product['Product']['id']),
array('class'=>'btn btn-primary col-md-offset-4', 
'data-product-id'=>$product['Product']['id']));
?>

$('a.btn').on('click', function(e){
        var this = $(this);
        var product_id = this.data('product-id');
        this.html('Item Added');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/cartphp_cart/carts/add/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {product_id: product_id},
            success: function(count) {
                $('#number-of-items').text(' ' + count);
                console.log(count);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ajax request is OK, than in your add method of CartsController
you can get it by

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    debug($this->request->data['product_id'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the data you've put in your ajax request by

```
if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
    pr($this->request->data['product_id']);
    // Or try printing the whole $this->request->data if you need other items.
}
```